# Strange behavior when adding longs in RobotC

Tags: c, robotics, lego-mindstorms, nxt

This is an example of the problem I am encountering with RobotC 3.62:

```
long heading;
task main()
{
    long num = 0;
    heading=num+90000;
}
```

This gives the result of `heading=24464`, which is not what I expected.

I tried replacing the 90000 part with a long containing 90000, and it gave the expected result. It seems as though writing the number 90000 causes some sort of overflow error `(90000-256^2=24464)`. This is odd since a long should hold "A whole number ranging from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647" . Do I need to cast it somehow? I am not familiar with C, could someone explain this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: It definitely sounds like it's storing it as a 16-bit int instead of a 32-bit long. The documentation on their site says "Note that the long, float and string data types are not supported on the Arduino 328 platforms." But I see you set the NXT tag, so I'm guessing that doesn't apply. It may be a compiler bug - I remember the NQC compiler having all sorts of strange problems back when I did Mindstorms programming. Have you contacted the vendor for support yet? Since it costs money, I would expect them to provide reasonable support.

Comment: Yeah, I am on an NXT Mindstorm for a robotics competition. It seems that I can get around it by first storing the number in a long, but this is an annoying solution for a problem that (as far as I can tell) should not exist. I will try contacting them and see if I can get any help. Thanks, any other suggestions?

Comment: Not really - the best I can suggest is throwing a few different ways of representing the problem at it and hope that one of them compiles correctly. Give the constant in hex, or as (long)90000, or add it up in chunks that are all 32,768 or less.

Comment: Do you have access to `stdint.h`?  It has `typedef`s such as `int32_t` and `defines` such as `INT32_MAX`.

Comment: It sounds like this compiler is just horribly broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with 3.X and has been previously fixed for 4.X and is resolved in the current public release of 4.X. There is a workaround for 3.x, however.

With the code you provided, the compiler output is truncating the result by only doing integer math. This was a previously found bug and later fixed, but still exists in older versions... here's the output:

```
long num = 0;
0025: CB000000 num:S00(slong) = 0 // long/float
heading = num + 90000;
0029: BD0800002B000000905F heading:G00(slong) = num:S00(slong) + 90000
```

As a workaround in 3.X, if you treat the constant as a "float" by specifying `90000.0`, the compiler will generate code that will not truncate the long because it'll do 32-bit level math (on the NXT, "int" are actually short ints, hence the truncation)

```
long num = 0;
0025: CB000000 num:S00(slong) = 0 // long/float
heading = num + 90000.0;
0029: AD2D04002B0000 S04(float) = num:S00(slong) // Store in temp variable :: Convert 'long' to 'float'
0030: 902D040000C8AF47 S04(float) += 90000 // Perform <op> on temp variable :: float
0038: 8C0800002D0400 heading:G00(slong) = S04(float) // Convert 'float' to 'long'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making `90000` a long, i.e.: `90000L.`

```
long heading;
task main()
{
    long num = 0;
    heading = num + 90000L;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I tried this and the code would not compile. `**Error**:Expected->';'. Found 'L'
**Error**:Undefined variable 'L'. 'short' assumed.
*Warning*:Meaningless statement -- no code generated`

Comment: Hmm, you actually aren't supposed to need the L on conforming versions of modern C -- it's supposed to use the smallest type that works for the value. Looks like you need a RobotC-specific answer, and I bet that's going to be:  *sorry, `long` is not supported.* You could test that with something like `int f(int a,int b){return a+b;}` then: look at the generated code, change all `int` to `long` and then see if the generated code changes. Or just look in the docs.

Comment: "conforming versions of modern C" i.e., not RobotC